# How are 2nd order ODEs solved in python? With two variables in each of two second order differentials?

Tags: python, algorithm, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have been given two second order ODEs and I've been asked to solve them with odeint in python.

These are the equations:

```
d^x(t)/dt^2 = 10dy(t)/dt + x(t) - (k + 1)(x(t))/z^3

d^2y(t)/dt^2 = - 10dy(t)/dt + y(t) - ((k+1)(y(t) + k))/z^3
```

where `z = np.sqrt((y+k)^2+x^2))`

I've been given initial variables (x, y, dxdt, dydt) I know their values but I'm not stuck on typing them so I won't put them here.

```
def function(init, time, k):
    xt = init[0]
    yt = init[1]
    z = np.sqrt((init[1]+k)^2+init[0]^2))
    dxdt = init[2]
    dydt = init[3]
    ddxddt = 10*dydt + xt - ((k+1)(xt))/z^3
    ddyddt = -10*dxdt + xt - ((k+1)(yt + k))/z^3
    return(dxdt, ddxddt, dydt, ddyddt)

init = [0.921, 0, 0, 3.0]
values = odeint(function, initial, time, args(k,))
```

After this I define initial, and define time, k, and put them in the odeint.

But I can see that I am doing something really wrong with my actual set up function. I don't understand how to split up 2nd order odes.

Comment: If you want somebody to help you, you need to show the "actual set up" function and explain in more detail what you find is "really wrong" with it.

Comment: I just replaced your original `init[2]`, `init[3]` etc. in the equations for `ddxddt` and `ddyddt` with the symbols you defined for them, and your equations don't match what you wrote in your question. Make sure you aren't confusing your `xt`, `yt`, `dxdt`, and `dydt` values in your `ddt` equations.

Comment: Could you please include the initial values and your call to `odeint`? This would make what's known as a "minimal, working example". It makes it much easier to answer a question if you don't have to guess at what's been done.

Comment: @mkrieger1 What do you mean set up function? I just need to understand how you solve 2nd order ODEs I don't even care if its not specific to my example. All the ones I've seen are easy, they just place their initial conditions in, then define dx and dy according to them, then they find ddx and ddy using the equations and take an array out. I tried this just and I got a straight line, which isn't correct its supposed to look weird.

Comment: @Richard I have done that. Thank you for the suggestion but there is no doubt in my mind that stating that doesn't matter.

Comment: @FirstNameBasis: Thank you. Stating it does matter, since it reduces the amount of thinking and work I have to do to help you. Maybe your equation behaves in ways specific to its initial conditions and parameters. Ideally you'd also include the time points you're solving at and the value of `k`.

Comment: I don't know what this set up function is supposed to be. *You* mentioned it in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few mistakes here.

First: `z^3` is not a power, it's the exclusive-or operation. In Python powers are done using the `**` operator, so you'll want to be writing `z**3`.

Second: You've misnamed the arguments of your function. Instead of:

```
def function(init, time, k):
```

you should have

```
def function(state, time, k):
```

since `state` evolves according to the derivatives the function returns. It will only have the initial values in the first timestep.

Third: your state interpretation and state deltas are inconsistent. You write:

```
xt   = init[0]
yt   = init[1]
dxdt = init[2]
dydt = init[3]
```

But later

```
return dxdt, ddxddt, dydt, ddyddt
```

This implies, among other things, that `dydt=ddxddt`. You should instead write:

```
xt, yt, dxdt, dydt = state
[....]
return dxdt, dydt, ddxddt, ddyddt
```

Note that you then have to ensure your initial conditions agree with the way you've ordered your state.

A minimum working example of a correct implementation might look like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(state, time, k):
  xt,yt,dxdt,dydt = state
  z               = np.sqrt((yt+k)**2+xt**2)
  ddxddt          = 10*dxdt + xt - ((k+1)*(xt    ))/z**3
  ddyddt          = -10*dydt + yt - ((k+1)*(yt + k))/z**3
  return dxdt, dydt, ddxddt, ddyddt

init = [
  0.921, #x[0]
  0,     #y[0]
  0,     #x'[0]
  3.0    #y'[0]
]

k = 1

times  = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
values = scipy.integrate.odeint(function, init, times, args=(k,), tfirst=False)

plt.plot(values)
plt.show()
```

and gives this output:

[image: Output of odeint]

Comment: I am so grateful. Thank you very much. I tried this before in fact, based on a youtube video, but I still didn't get the answer. 

If anyone is looking at this post after me, try making sure the array you return is ordered in that way.

Comment: @FirstNameBasis: No problem. If this answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you would upvote it (by clicking the gray up arrow next to the question) and/or accept it (by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the question). On StackOverflow you can upvote as many answers as you'd like, but you can accept only one.